# Joomla! JDatabase::getErrorNum() is deprecated, use exception handling instead

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have the following code:

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('#__users');
    $db->setQuery($query);

    // Check for a database error.
    if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
        JError::raiseWarning(500, $db->getErrorMsg());
    }       

    $result = $db->loadResult();
```

**Now getErrorNum as well as JError are deprecated.**

Just to clarify, JError and $db->getErrorNum() are NOT deprecated in Joomla 2.5 but are in Joomla! 3.0. So this question has value for somebody who develops for 2.5 but wants to make an easy upgrade to 3.X series.

So **with what exactly to replace them** so that I can properly check for database errors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('*')
      ->from('#__users');

try
{
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadResult();
}
catch (RuntimeException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

JError is NOT deprecated in Joomla 2.5 - but in Joomla 3.0 (Platform 12.1 onwards) so for Joomla 2.5 this is not an issue. JError is being replaced with the php exceptions (link to the php guide [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php))

There is also a Joomla forum question about this [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=642&t=664690)

Using exception is also the case for getErrorNum() - again read the php documentation link above for more info. There's a nice mysql example on the page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#78591).

Answer (score 1):

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('*')
  ->from('#__tablename');

try
{
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadObjectList();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $app->enqueueMessage(JText::_($e->getMessage()), 'error');
}
```

and redirect to your url. Error message will be displayed